# Mocha + ZombieJs, document is not defined

Tags: zombie.js

I'm using zombiejs + mocha to write some tests for a library that manipulates the DOM, it uses JavaScript native functions like document.createElement(), my problem is, when I run the tests I get an exception saying that 'document is not defined'.

Is it a problem with zombiejs, or with jsDOM? and how can I fix it?

here is an example of my code:

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <script src="mocha.js"></script>
    <script src="expect.js"></script>
    <title>XS UI Tests</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="../lib/mylibrary.js"></script>

    <script>
      mocha.setup('bdd');
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="table"></div>
    <div id="controls"></div>
    <div id="form"></div>

    <div id="mocha"></div>

    <script src="tests.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**in tests.js:**

```
var expect  = require( 'expect.js' )
  , Zombie  = require( 'zombie'    )
  , browser = new Zombie( { debug: true } )
;

describe( 'XS UI Tests:', function() {
  before( function( done ) {
    browser.visit( 'http://localhost:8080/test/ui.html', done );
  } );

  it( 'expect ui.html to be loaded', function() {
    expect( browser.success ).to.be( true );
  } );

  describe( 'Table Tests:', function() {
    it( 'expect div#table ( table container ) to exist', function() {
      expect( browser.query( "#table" ) ).to.be.ok();
    } );
  } );
} );
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `document` object is contained within the zombie browser. If your code doesn't find `document`, it is likely you are not running it within the zombie sandbox context.

Are you loading your library via `zombie.visit('/page/with/library')` or are you requiring it directly and trying to use it within the test?

It is best to test complete webpages rather than libraries. You should create a test page that has a few buttons/links on it which test different functions of the library, and `pressButton` or `visit` those with zombie.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.

Indeed I load my library via 'require' in my test script.

I just modified my code to load the library that I test directly in the HTML, but it doesn't load!

Comment: @Khalifa Make sure it works in the browser, then try adding some debugging statements to the zombie API, specifically in the [resources](https://github.com/assaf/zombie/blob/master/src/zombie/resources.coffee) object.

Comment: In the browser it works, no problem, and I have already debugging messages in my library, it seems  that my library doesn't load!

Comment: You should be able to turn verbose on in the zombie options, try that and see if it gets you anywhere.

Comment: it seems like there is a path issue with npm / nodejs on cygwin. I just tested ZombieJS on a ubuntu virtual machine and everything is working fine now! Thank you very much for your answers.

Comment: Zombie indeed, issue fixed nearly a year after it was encountered!